# CentOS7 How increase font size in Gnome Terminal?

Tags: centos, rhel, gnome

Any idea how to increase font size in Gnome Terminal for  CentOS 7?

I found some tips here, but I couldnt find this menu `System -> Preferences -> Fonts menu option`
https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_CentOS_Desktop_Fonts#Changing_Font_Settings

Font settings are controlled via the Font Preferences dialog which is accessed via the System -> Preferences -> Fonts menu option

Comment: Those sound like directions for the KDE terminal Konsole. Go back to whoever gave you the directions.

Comment: I found this on google, not my case, I have Gnome, Only what I found is Settings > Universal Access is : `Large Text`, But this is not eough,

Comment: There is really no simple option to change text size (like 10,14, 16...) like in Ubuntu... ?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved via Terminal Menu > Edit > Preferences